# Windows Phone 8.1 AppBar Taking Up Unnecessary Room

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have an `AppBar` in my app which holds only a secondary command.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="refresh" Click="Refresh_WebView"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

However, it still leaves enough of the `AppBar` "visible" (you don't have to pull it up to see it) to leave room for the PrimaryCommands that aren't there. This is wasting a lot of space. The Store is doing the same thing in the Downloads section, but the `AppBar` doesn't take up that unnecessary space. How can I specify that I don't want mine to, either?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="refresh" Click="Refresh_WebView"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Edited the answer after I figured what you wanted! This should work.

Comment: Hmm... Looks good in the VS designer, but when I actually deploy the app it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Also, `IsOpen` should be capitalized. Very minor issue, but creates problems when copying and pasting.

Comment: Right, I just understood your problem. You want to hide the whole thing so just the 3 dots are visible?